# Perferct forward a copied std::tuple

Tags: c++, tuples, c++14, perfect-forwarding, stdapply

I need a bit of help. I need to perfect forward a tuple in a specific way. Imagine this

```
template <typename F, typename... Args>
auto package_task(F&& func, Args&&... args) -> std::function<void()>
{
    //for the purposes of this example imagine capture to be std::move and
    //to be inplace in the lambdas' capture.
    auto callable = capture(std::forward<F>(func));
    auto params = capture(std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...));

    return [callable , params]() mutable { std::apply(callable, params); };
}
```

the task that is packaged will be executed later on a different thread but when I call apply I need the "callable" to have it's params expanded from the tuple and forwarded exactly like they were passed in the `package_task` function. I can't use `forward_as_tuple` since I am copying/moving the arguments and the callable to be executed later. I need something like

```
template <typename F, typename... Args>
auto package_task(F&& func, Args&&... args) -> std::function<void()>
{
    //for the purposes of this example image capture to be std::move and
    //to be inplace in the lambdas' capture.
    auto callable = capture(std::forward<F>(func));
    auto params = capture(std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...));

    return [callable , params]() mutable { std::apply_but_expand_as<Args&&…>(callable, params); };
}
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you're rewriting `bind`, you could check how standard bind or boost bind does it.

Comment: well capture is actualy a move_on_copy wrapper that does std::move when copy constructor is invoked. This allows me to work with std::function and move-only objects that I want to capture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to make a one-shot callable that forwards its arguments through, the best you can do with C++17 or earlier is:

```
template <typename F, typename... Args>
auto package_task(F&& func, Args&&... args) -> std::function<void()>
{
    return [func = std::forward<F>(func),
            args_tuple = std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...)]
           () mutable
    {
        return std::apply([](auto&&... args){
            return std::invoke(
                std::forward<F>(func),
                std::forward<Args>(args)...
                );
        }, args_tuple);
    };
}
```

That is, you `forward` the `Args` into a tuple, `apply` the tuple and then `forward` them back out.

---

In C++20, thanks to [P0780](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0780r2.html), this can be simplified to:

```
template <typename F, typename... Args>
auto package_task(F&& func, Args&&... args) -> std::function<void()>
{
    return [func = std::forward<F>(func),
            ...args = std::forward<Args>(args)] () mutable
    {
        return std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    };
}
```

Comment: well this kinda works great on gcc. Msvc 2015/2017 can't really handle the expansion inside the generic lambda and gives me this.  error: C3520: 'Args': parameter pack must be expanded in this context. I have no idea how to make it work there though. For now I can get away with a std::move instead of the std::forward in the invoke call since the lambda owns the data and it works on msvc as well

Comment: This works well with gcc/clang/mingw except msvc. Any ideas how to work around that error I mentioned above with msvc?

Comment: i guess the auto&& trips the msvc compiler, replacing it with std::decay_t<Args>& fixed it